# wpf pass datatemplate to new window

Tags: wpf, window, datatemplate

i need to send a DataTemplate to a new window for printing purposes.

1) I have create a general Window lets name it **PrintPreview** that holds the followings:

**FlowDocument** > **BlockUiContainer** > **ContentControl** (Responsible to display the DataTemplate that i will send to it)

The problem is that the bindings inside the datatemplate are not working. (not for all cases )

For example:
i have this datatemplate somewhere in my application

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyPrintPreview">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty1,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeViewModel},Path=SomeProperty2}"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The above DataTemplate is working very well and show both properties in my current View (UserControl)
but when i send this DataTemplate to the New Window PrintPreview i have the following issues

The 1st  TextBlock (SomeProperty1) fails to display the content

The 2nd TextBlock (SomeProperty2) show just fine!

i don't know how to make this work. or if am doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set or bind the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` to an object that contains the properties that the elements in the `ContentTemplate` try to bind to.

So set the `ContentTemplate` property of the `ContentControl` to your `DataTemplate` and set the `Content` property to the actual object to bind to. That's how a `ContentControl` is supposed to be used.

Also note that for your first binding to work, the `ContentControl` must be a child of a `UserControl` because you are binding to `SomeProperty1` of the parent `UserControl`. If there is no parent `UserControl`, the binding will always fail.

Comment: thank you , but why the property 2 working? the SomeViewModel Resource is defined also in the user control level which is my current view

Comment: It doesn't rely on a DataContext but on a resource that apparently is in scope.